# Why is my shell script not executing?

Tags: command-line, bash, gedit

I executed it in terminal using:

```
sh script.sh
```

And I get this error:

```
sh: 0 can't open script.sh
```

Comment: `ls -l` to where your script resides?

Comment: FYI `sh` does **not** "*execute the script in bash"* - it executes it in `sh`, which by default is `dash` on Ubuntu systems: see [DashAsBinSh](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error has nothing to do with gedit and/or nano. Your script call is a bit wrong. This error occurs, if you start `sh` with an non-existing file in the current folder. Therefore start your script with a full path:

```
sh /path/to/your/script.sh
```

or change your current folder and start your script inside this folder:

```
cd /path/to/your
sh script.sh
```